# MySql : Get Ranks Heavy Query Optimization - help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

i've only got the following table in my database :

**scores Table**

> Field...............|........Type.........|..Null..|..Key..|...........Default.................|..Extra
>   
>   ...............................................................................................................................................
>   
>   id....................|...........int(20)...|..NO...|..PRI..|..NULL.............................|..auto_increment
>   scr..................|...........int(20)...|..NO...|..........|.....0.................................|..........................
>   player_name..|..varchar(150)..|..NO...|..........|..NULL............................|.........................
> location...........|.varchar(5).......|..NO...|..........|..NULL............................|.........................
>   DateUpdated..|..timestamp......|..NO...|..........|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|..on-update

currently i've got an index on the id field .

i'm dealing with 1 million records in my case .
each player will have one record only in the database.

i want to retrieve the global ranking of a specific player named : john with id : 682 as per the following example:

> Rank..........Id.......SCR......DateUpdated
>   -------------------------------------------------------------
>   15257...53264.......62........2013-3-10 16:45:37
>   15258...3533.........62........2013-3-10 16:45:37
>   15259...7283.........62........2013-3-13 16:45:37
>   15260...386...........61........2013-3-09 18:55:25
>   15261...78252.......61........2013-3-10 13:33:21
>   15262...682...........61........2013-3-10 16:45:37        <== this is our player
>   15263...9263.........61........2013-3-10 16:45:37
>   15264...7263.........61........2013-3-10 16:56:25
>   15265...7826.........60........2013-3-10 12:26:37
>   15266...9276.........60........2013-3-10 15:22:37
>   15267...932872.....60........2013-3-13 11:45:37

the player appears in the middle with 5 players above and 5 players below
Note that ranks is ordered by scr then DateUpdated

this is my query which brings these results :

```
 SELECT id,
  scr,
  player_name,
  location,
  dateupdated,
  rank
FROM
  (SELECT id,
    scr,
    player_name,
    location,
    dateupdated
  FROM scores
  WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM
      (SELECT id
      FROM scores
      WHERE id IN
        (SELECT id
        FROM scores
        WHERE scr >=
          (SELECT scr FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
          )
        AND id     != 1140188
        AND id NOT IN
          (SELECT id
          FROM scores
          WHERE scr IN
            (SELECT scr FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
            )
          AND dateupdated >=
            (SELECT dateupdated FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
            )
          )
        ORDER BY scr ASC,
          dateupdated ASC
        )
      ORDER BY scr,
        dateupdated ASC limit 0,
        5
      ) AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id FROM
      (SELECT id FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
      ) AS g
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id
    FROM
      (SELECT id
      FROM scores
      WHERE id IN
        (SELECT id
        FROM scores
        WHERE scr <=
          (SELECT scr FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
          )
        AND id     != 1140188
        AND id NOT IN
          (SELECT id
          FROM scores
          WHERE scr IN
            (SELECT scr FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
            )
          AND dateupdated <
            (SELECT dateupdated FROM scores WHERE id = 1140188
            )
          )
        ORDER BY scr ASC,
          dateupdated ASC
        )
      ORDER BY scr DESC,
        dateupdated ASC limit 0,
        5
      ) AS s
    )
  ORDER BY scr DESC,
    dateupdated ASC
  ) AS A
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT l.id             AS id2,
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS Rank
  FROM scores l
  JOIN
    (SELECT @curRow := 0
    ) r
  ORDER BY scr DESC,
    dateupdated ASC
  ) AS B ON A.id = B.id2;
```

but this query takes around 8 sec on my local machine and it consumes a lot of resources, implementing this on a web service will end up in a disaster.

can any one provide any hints here, even an entirely new query is welcomed ..

please HELP !!!!!

Comment: The formatting of the query should be preserved as an example of ***"how not to write queries"***

Comment: Have you consider persisting your model with an O/RM or something similar that would produce a bit more elegant MYSQL code?

Comment: pigeons needs help ... !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
all_ranked.*
FROM (select rank 
      from (SELECT l.id             AS id2,
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS Rank
            FROM scores l
            JOIN
                (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                ORDER BY scr DESC, dateupdated ASC
            ) AS B) 
      where B.id=1234567) as rank_record, <--- just one record - value of rank
      (SELECT l.id             AS id2,
            @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS Rank
            FROM scores l
            JOIN
                (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                ORDER BY scr DESC, dateupdated ASC
            ) AS all_ranked <--- all ranked users
where all_ranked.rank>=rank_record.rank-5 and all_ranked.rank>=rank_record.rank+5;
```

Comment: Dear StanislavL, there is an error in your query, i've removed the closing bracket preceding the "AS B" and it resulted in more than 11 records !! Thank you very much for the fast response

Comment: Dear StanislavL, i've fixed the issues.
some Temp variables naming, and arithmetic errors.
works good but it takes about 3.5 seconds .
i don't think it is too good to implement on API ... still heavy :(